# Некорректно увеличивает объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу понять как увеличить Scriptable Object.
Делаю так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит, что я увеличиваю Scriptable Object а не что отрисовывает в итоге Unity.

Comment: Не приводите код картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizeDelta изменяет размер прямоугольника а не его содержимое. `rect.localScale` будет менять именно масштаб